# Django Translation of String Constants

Tags: python, django, translation

In Django, I have a file of string constants (such as error messages) that I will be passing to templates as user visible content.  I want to use these with Django's translation framework.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use Django's [lazy translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation) in your constants file:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy

STRING_CONSTANT1 = ugettext_lazy("Here is some string")
...
```

---

If you use `gettext_lazy`, you may run into the following error when rendering templates:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\uxxxx' in
>   position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Using `ugettext_lazy` rather than `gettext_lazy` solves this.

Comment: If you're missing pieces of the puzzle with this answer, take a look at https://medium.com/@nolanphillips/a-short-intro-to-translating-your-site-with-django-1-8-343ea839c89b which helped me out